# Set a homepage and html code

Tags: magento2, error, adminhtml, configuration

I have beginner's problem with my magento 2 files. I cannot set my homepage correctly. When I've pasted my HTML code into `Content->Pages` it results showing my HTML Code not content what it contains. How to set homepage correctly with having code already? Please give me a solutions because I do it for the first time.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Open `Home page` from `Admin->Content->Page` and click on `Show/Hide Editor` button.

Step 2: After clicking `Show/Hide Editor` button, Editor will disable Paste your HTML code in textarea and click on save page button.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much it works. However I need some help yet. After clicking button and pasting my code on homepage not full of it is showing.  In Editor I got everything but it is clean HTML without any css addons. How to fix it?

Comment: It would be great if you can past your html in question